# Two-way binding on Native Control causes severe crash in Xamarin Forms crossplatform

Tags: binding, xamarin.forms, crash

The application closes without showing any error, this happens when I try to enter some data an Entry Box, I'm using SQLite and I have ViewModels binding with the Views, using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the model.
I do not know why that happens, as long as you do not try to enter some value the application does not close.

This is the ViewModel:

```
class PersonViewModel : PersonModel
{
    public ICommand Save { get; private set; }
    public ICommand Update { get; private set; }
    public ICommand Delete { get; private set; }
    public ICommand New { get; private set; }

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        Save = new Command(() =>
        {
            PersonModel model = new PersonModel()
            {
                Name = Name,
                Lastname = Lastname,
                Country = Country,
                Email = Email,
                Date = Date,
                City = City
            };

            using (var context = new DataContext()) // Cierra la conexion (Dispose) cuando sale el scope 
            {
                context.Insert(model);
            }
        });

        Update = new Command(() =>
        {
            PersonModel model = new PersonModel()
            {
                Name = Name,
                Lastname = Lastname,
                Country = Country,
                Email = Email,
                Date = Date,
                City = City,
                IdPerson = IdPerson
            };

            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                context.Update(model);
            }
        });

        Delete = new Command(() =>
        {
            PersonModel model = new PersonModel()
            {
                Name = Name,
                Lastname = Lastname,
                Country = Country,
                Email = Email,
                Date = Date,
                City = City,
                IdPerson = IdPerson
            };

            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                context.Delete(model);
            }
        });

        New = new Command(() =>
        {
            PersonModel model = new PersonModel()
            {
                Name = string.Empty,
                Lastname = string.Empty,
                Country = string.Empty,
                Email = string.Empty,
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                City = string.Empty
            };
        });
    }
}
```

This is the View:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ProbandoSqlite.Views.PersonsView">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Persons" Font="25" TextColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
            <Entry Placeholder="Name" Text="{Binding Name}"></Entry>
            <Entry Placeholder="Lastname" Text="{Binding Lastname}"></Entry>
            <Entry Placeholder="Email" Text="{Binding Email}"></Entry>
            <Entry Placeholder="Country" Text="{Binding Country}"></Entry>
            <Entry Placeholder="City" Text="{Binding City}"></Entry>
            <DatePicker Date="{Binding Date}"></DatePicker>

            <Button Text="Save" Command="{Binding Save}"></Button>
            <Button Text="New"  Command="{Binding New}"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnShow" Text="Show" Clicked="BtnShow_Clicked"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>  
</ContentPage>
```

This is the code behind the View:

```
public partial class PersonsView : ContentPage
{
    public PersonsView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.BindingContext = new PersonViewModel();
    }

    private void BtnShow_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((NavigationPage)Parent).PushAsync(new ShowView());
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way we can help you if you can't take the time to show us what you're doing by posting the relevant portions of your code.  A vague description of a problem with no detail is meaningless.

Comment: Look at this is the code

Comment: what about PersonModel?

Comment: Is there no exception shown when debugging, neither?

Comment: no, it runs well, even, probe and remove the biding to the Name field, and if I can enter text without closing the application, it only closes when this binding

Comment: PersonalModel is the model that represents a person, this has an Id, Name, and other fields. PersonalModel inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged, so I have a property public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       in each property the method OnPropertyChanged ("propertyname") is called.